# The footer on my flashcards are not aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, right-to-left, xepersian, flashcards

I'm using the xepersian package to write Persian language flash cards. I want to have a footer on the front and the back of the card that shows what particular exercise this word comes from (e.g., "Vocabulary 1" or "Grammar 2"). I am using a 3x9 grid for this.

Unfortunately, the text on the Persian side of the cards is not properly aligned, with its footer being shifted by exactly 1 column, so that the footer for the right column is in the center, the center column's footer is on the left, and the left column's footer is off the page.

I've been experimenting with `\vskip`, `\vspace`, `\centering`, `\raggedright` and so on, but none seem to work.

A piece of my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[frame,frontgrid,backgrid,letterpaper,12pt]{flacards}
\pagesetup{3}{8}

\usepackage{xepersian}


\settextfont[Scale=1]{ScheherazadeNew-Regular.ttf}

\renewcommand{\cardtextstylef}{\huge}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\latin}
\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\hskip-0.15\linewidth\thecardno}
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{\hskip+0.15\linewidth\thecardno}


 \begin{document}

\input{Lesson_5/1_Vocabulary_1.tex}
\input{Lesson_5/2_Vocabulary_2.tex}
\input{Lesson_5/3_Reading.tex}
\input{Lesson_5/4_Technology_Related_Words}
\input{Lesson_5/5_About Shopping}
\input{Lesson_5/6 _Clothing}
\input{Lesson_5/7_Verbs_Phrases}


\end{document}
```

And then for the first section I have:

```
\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\hskip-0.15\linewidth\thecardno \vspace{-0.8cm}
\center{\latin{\tiny{Lesson 5 - Vocabulary 1}}}}
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{\hskip+0.15\linewidth\thecardno \center{\latin{\tiny{Lesson 5 - Vocabulary 1}}}}

\card{بایَد}{\lr{Must/Should}}
\card{بِپُرسَم (پُرس)}{\lr{I should/may ask}}
\card{بِخَرَم (خَر)}{\lr{I should/may buy}}
\card{بِرَوید (بِرین)}{\lr{Go! (Plural \& Formal)}}
\card{تَخفیفِ دانِشجویی}{\lr{Student discount}}
\card{می تَوانَم (می تونَم)}{\lr{I can/I am able to}}
\card{مُشتَری}{\lr{Client/Customer}}
\card{می خواهَم \\(می خوام)}{\lr{I want}}
\card{جِناب}{\lr{Sir}}
\card{صَبر کُنید \\(صَبر کُنین)}{\lr{Wait! (Plural \& Formal)}}
\card{قِیمَت}{\lr{Price}}
\card{هَمکار}{\lr{Co-worker}}
\card{کِتاب‌فُروشی}{\lr{Bookstore}}
\card{پِیدایَش کُنَم \\(پِیداش کُنَم)}{\lr{I should/may find it}}
\card{لَحظه}{\lr{Moment}}
\card{بِپُرسید (بِپُرسین)}{\lr{Ask! (Plural \& Formal)}}
```

If you run this, you'll see the shift in columns. Does anyone have any idea on how to properly align this?

Comment: we can not run this, as we don't have your input files. Make a proper example that can be really used for a test.

Comment: I format footers using `\hbox to \textwdith{\rlap{left}\hfill center\hfill\llap{right}}` to center the center section precisely.  To prevent overlaps, lose the `\rlap` and `\llap` and hope the whole thing fits.